# Matlab fit NonlinearLeastSquares for Python

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, least-squares

I rewrite code written in Matlab for Python and I can´t resolve correctly the fit function in Python.
Code in Matlab:

```
y = *Array 361x1*;
x = *Array 361x1*;
y1 = *Single value 1x1*;
x1 = *Single value 1x1*;

fo = fitoptions('Method','NonlinearLeastSquares','Lower',[-Inf,-Inf],'Upper',[Inf, Inf],'Startpoint',[0.0,0.0]);

ft = fittype( @(A,B, x) A.*x.^2 + B.*x + y1 - A.*x1.^2 - B.*x1, 'independent','x','dependent','y','options',fo);

[fitobject,gof,out] = fit(x,y,ft);

A = fitobject.A;
B = fitobject.B;
```

I tried the solution in Python through Scipy Least Squares and based on [this article](https://mphumphreys.wordpress.com/2019/02/08/matlab-to-python-2/). I wrote the following code:

```
ft = least_squares(lambda coeffs: coeffs[0]*x**2 + coeffs[1]*x + y1 - coeffs[0]*x1**2 - coeffs[1]*x1, [0, 0], bounds=([-np.inf, -np.inf], [np.inf, np.inf]))
print(ft('x'))
```

Obviously it is not correct (array y is not considered in Python code) and I get different values for coefficients A and B. I´ve already tried difrferent functions like curve%fit, etc. But with no result...

Comment: I can only emphasize to use the NLopt-toolbox from the MIT: https://nlopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ it got far more optimization algorithms with a neat matlab/octave interface + python, all open-source, and -- to my experience -- often more accurate and faster indeed =)

Comment: What's the error that you get? Can you include some example data?

Comment: I don´t get any error. I just get different values for coefficients A and B in Python :-/ I don´t know how to share input data while y and x is an array with 361 elements, while y1 and x1 are just single values (y1 = -56,7, x1 = 235,9). I checked the nlopt but it doesn´t seems to be useful for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use scipy.optimize's [curve_fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html). Assuming `x` and `y` are numpy.ndarrays containing the data:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def fitme(x, *coeffs_and_args):
    A, B, x1, y1 = coeffs_and_args
    return A*x**2 + B*x + y1 - A*x1**2 - B*x1 

popt, pcov = curve_fit(lambda  x, A, B: fitme(x, A, B, x1, y1), x, y)
```

Then the array `popt` contains the optimal values for the parameters and `pcov` the estimated covariance of `popt`.